# count occurrences of combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a table of counts for every combination of two columns. This was the best I could come up with, but Im not sure how to get it in the correct form. Is there a method or something that would make this easier?

```
from itertools import product
d = {'ballot1': ['a','b','a','a','b','a','a','b'],
     'ballot1_x':['c','c','d','d','a','a','a','a']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(d)
for i in product(set(df1['ballot1']), set(df1['ballot1_x'])):
    print(str(i[0])+str(i[1]))
```

GOAL (as a dataframe):

```
  a  b
c 1  1
d 2  0
a 2  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `crosstab` from pandas ([detail documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)):

```
from pandas import crosstab
d = {'ballot1': ['a','b','a','a','b','a','a','b'],
     'ballot1_x':['c','c','d','d','a','a','a','a']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(d)

result_df = crosstab(df1['ballot1_x'], df1['ballot1'])
print(result_df)
```

Result:

```
     ballot1    a  b
ballot1_x      
a               2  2
c               1  1
d               2  0
```